# Bash - open command not working

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm taking the One Month Rails course and I'm just learning how to navigate the command line.  I'm trying to open my Documents folder from the command line as a test.  When I type "pwd" it shows up as the working directory.  When I type "open ." it says:

sh.exe": open: command not found

According to the video tutorial, you should be able to open folders directly from the command line.  So what am I doing wrong?  Help please!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the command `explorer .` instead.

Comment: I know this answer is more than 4 years old, but thanks.  I'm a noob at RoR and using Git Bash.  I was following a tutorial that stated to use the open command and got this error.  Your contribution was really helpful, years down the line.

Comment: No problem, glad my answer could help! We're all noobs at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Ruby on Rails problem at this point; you're just shelling out, and having trouble determining which commands are available in your platform's shell.

The command that you actually try to run will depend on the platform that you're running on.  (We can see that it's windows, based on that `sh.exe` that you mention.)

What platform was the original tutorial written for?  Some flavor of Unix, or perhaps Mac?  I know that on the Mac, 'open' is a command that will work in the shell.

Since you're on Windows (based on the .exe extension), you need to run a command that will work well *on Windows.*  As jvperrin states in the other answer, that *may* be explorer.

Comment: `open` is a pretty solid identifier for mac.

Comment: Yeah, I just wasn't sure if it also existed in some Unix or Linux distros.